# Rails 5 converts object to a string when passing on the params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 I have my sign up page using `form_for` helper to create a user, which is then directed to my custom confirm page.

```
  <%= form_for @user, url: {action: :confirm} do |f| %>
```

In my confirm controller I can access parameters without any problem. This is how they are displayed in the console.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"<longBlaString>", 
"user"=>{"name"=>"Railsmastanot", 
         "email"=>"example@domain.com", 
         "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
         "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, 
"commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

I then use

`<%= button_to "Yes", {controller: "users", action: "create",  params: params}, class: 'btn btn-success' %>`

to redirect to the actual `users#create` method. Inside I am trying to access parameters, e.g. `params[:user][:email]` but get an error

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Examining console reveals than my parameters hash turned into this:

```
Parametes:
 {"authenticity_token"=>"longBlaString", 
"commit"=>"Sign up",
"user"=>"email=example@domain.com&name=Railsmastanot&password=
<myActualPassword!>&password_confirmation=<myActualPassword!>", 
"utf8"=>"✓"}
```

So the user key no longer holds the hash, but a string. Is this supposed to happen or a bug? If not a bug, what is the correct way to handle this? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I figured out that `params` is not actually a hash in Rails 5. If I pass parameters like  `params: params.to_unsafe_h` it works, but I am not sure this is safe to do.

Comment: You want to create sign up form but after posting data why you need to redirect your page to create ? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: My sign up form works fine. It passes parameters as expected. Before, I could create users without any problems. Now I want to add an intermediate confirm page, so [new user form] => [confirm]=>[create user]. Parameters from [new user form] to [confirm] pass as expected. But when I pass params from [confirm] to [create user] the params hash is modified as described above.

Comment: in users#create what happens if you do sample_hash = JSON.parse(params). Can you sample_hash like how you use? put a byebug and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got a good answer here but it didn't really answer the question of what is going on. The root of the problem is the fact that in Rails 5 [params returns an object, not a hash](http://eileencodes.com/posts/actioncontroller-parameters-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-a-hash/). So actually doing `params: params.to_unsafe_h` in Rails 5 seems to be equivalent to simply `params: params` in Rails 4. I was told that this is done simply because Rails 5 wants you to be aware of exactly what data you're transmitting so that you don't unwittingly transfer secure data unnecessarily (e.g. passing a whole user object when it's not required). It's an extension of the [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) feature already implemented in Rails 4.

As far as I see this doesn't really introduce any safety risks in this case, since the `params.to_unsafe_h` is converted back to parameter object straight away.

Answer (score 2):

**This can be done like this**

1. Add column confirmed in user table
2. Save user when form is submitted with confirmed => false and take id from it.
3. Then from confirmation page send user id with confirmation.
4. If information confirmed then update user with confirmed = true.
5. If information not confirmed then delete user.

**Method you are using may not be safe because parameters are printed in confirmation page.**

Comment: Is that the way to do it? Seems kind of unclean creating a user before confirmation, or is that a normal practice?

Comment: Also could you explain what do you mean by 'may not be safe'? The parameters that I am printing in confirmation page are only the name and the email, not the password.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, `params.permit!` will also do the trick.

Comment: You might want to expand on this by explaining what that code does and then remove the statement "In addition to the accepted answer". You're surely aiming to have _your_ answer accepted aren't you?